# Model State Errors (or) Custom exceptions of a certain type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, exception

I have an application ASP.NET MVC with JQUERY application that throws 4 kinds of errors

1. Unhanded exceptions (400, 403,500 503 etc) - throw generic exceptions
2. **NOT SEVERE Expected exceptions/ errors** (custom exceptions)- e.g. Trying to look for a contact that does not exist in the system - The system needs to throw "Contact_not_found_exception" and show this to the user as "Contact does not exist in the system" . It does not stop the user from doing anything else but its just to alert the user
3. **VERY SEVERE Expected exceptions/ errors** (custom exceptions)- e.g. Trying to create a contact that already exist in the system - The system needs to throw "Contact_duplicated_exception" and show this to the user as "Contact was previously created. Could not proceed as name should be unique"
4. Model state errors (UI). Errors that I add to modelstate to showup on the page using @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

Client validation errors which are caught on the front end and application errors are
caught in global.asax

I am looking for a good way to catch errors/exceptions of type 2 and 3 and return it back to AJAX() Calls with a certain severity type "Critical" vs "Warning".

I have been following the link for Handling validation errors on Ajax calls in Asp.net MVC

http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/11/handling-validation-errors-on-ajax.html

I cannot generalize and add all the model state errors as ModelStateException. As most of these errors/exceptions are of a certain severity type and my front end (JQUERY) should read this type of error and do different actions.

1. How do I create a dictionary of custom exception , severity type ?
2. How do I throw these and add it to model state error.
3. How do I catch these globally using Custom Handle Erro Arrtibute and IExceptionFilter

Thanks,
Hephs